# What is the difference between 'int [] arr1=null;' and 'int [] arr1=int [5];' regarding memory allocation

Tags: java, c++, c, memory, memory-management

I'd like to know what is the difference difference between

```
int []  arr1=null;
```

and

```
int [] arr1=int [5];
```

regarding the memory allocation? I read somewhere that null is a reference variable and therefore there's a memory allocation in the heap, but I assume that `int[]` is also a reference variable, Isn't it? So there's a difference anyway?

In general in what examples of assignments can I see difference between heap memory and stack memory allocation in Java/C++?

Comment: What is the context of the variable declaration - is it a local variable, an instance variable, a static variable? Also, it's probably only worth asking about *either* C++ or Java to start with.

Comment: Your question makes no sense in C++.

Comment: I suggest we remove the c++ tag.

Comment: That's not even valid Java, is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for your question is exactly shown in the figure given below
[image]

**In JAVA**
[image: IN JAVA]

`int [] arr1=int [5];` is invalid in java

Comment: c++ does not work in the Heap at all?

Comment: i can't say NO, since because in c++ you can create that kind of environment.....as you know heap memory in java is made of c malloc.....and also see this article http://www.javamex.com/java_equivalents/memory_management.shtml

Comment: so we can make heap using C programming

Comment: yes since c has dynamic memory allocation functionality

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan sir....so if c can do that then c++ can also do.....so having all features similar to java can we say c++ is better than java

Comment: c++ is object oriented like java, can make heap memory , has pointer which java does'nt have....

Comment: please first take a look at this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32681/discussion-between-nidhishkrishnan-and-user2018186)

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
int[]  arr1=null;
```

just creates variabel `arr1` that is a reference to array. The reference is `null`, so only reference itself was allocated. It guess it is about 4 bytes.

However

```
int[] arr1= new int[5];
```

additionally allocates an array that contains 5 integers, i.e. additionally `4*5` bytes. Totally `4 + 4*5 = 24` bytes.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ this syntax is invalid, but change it to :

```
int * arr1=nullptr;

int * arr2=new int [5];
```

and it does essentially the same thing:

The `arr1` in my example is a reference/pointer to some memory, that doesn't refer/point to anything currently.

The `arr2` refers/points to an array of 5 integers, which are allocated on the heap.

If at some later stage, we need to make `arr1` point at ten integers, we can (again, in C++) do:

```
arr1 = new int[10];
```

In C++ you would also have to `delete` the values:

```
delete [] arr2; 

delete [] arr1;
```

Note that it's valid to delete something that points at null, but it is not valid to delete an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the second version allocates a five-element `int` array, whereas the first doesn't.

There's also memory set aside for the `arr1` reference itself, but that's the same in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

null is Java's way of saying that it is not allocated any heap or not pointing to anything. Where as in the second version java allocates array of 5 ints on heap and lets your variable arr1(which is on the stack btw) to point to it.

Answer (score 1):

In Java,

```
int [] arr1=int [5];
```

It creates both the array object(since in java an array is considered as object) and the space in memory for `5` primitive(`int`) elements. And initializes each primitive elements to there default value (`0` for int). And finally the reference to that object is given to reference variable `arr1`.

```
int []  arr1=null;
```

Only creates a reference variable `arr1` which is pointing to nothing. This line specifies that `arr1` will might be in future contain the reference of the object which will contain the array of primitive integers.

Answer (score 0):

Just talking about java.

Type of int[] doesn't have any instance of int. it's a pointer of array of int. So it can point the instance of array of int.

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a, b, c;

        a = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
        b = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        c = a;
        System.out.println(c.length);
        c = b;
        System.out.println(c.length);
    }
}
```

a, b are pointing instance of array of int. and at the last line of code above, c and b point same instance.